# Display URL as meta facebook in VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, meta, facebook-iframe

I need to display url using facebook meta card. Let's take the following link:
http://www.timescolonist.com/news/b-c/westjet-expands-service-from-vancouver-with-60-more-flights-1.23158436

On messenger it displays the following card:
[image]

Does anyone has an idea about how to display those card on a VueJS app ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta

Comment: I was meaning display url inside a component , not set my own meta card.